# Are "Where are they now?" questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'd like to know "what happened next" to some well-known games authors and personalities from the 1980's UK home computing industry. Are such questions on topic, or as the facts will undoubtedly change over time does this mean they don't fit with the "correct answer" methodology?

Answer (score 5):

These questions wouldn't be about retrocomputing *per se*, and we have already decided that the [history of companies/people](//meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/59/278) is off topic, so I'd have to say "**No, this is not on topic**". These questions would be best answered by a biography, not a computing site.